# polar pcolormesh plot projected onto cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

To simplify, as much as possible, a [question I already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409065/cartpy-and-pcolormesh-how-to-project-polar-data-onto-a-map), how would you OVERLAY or PROJECT a polar plot onto a cartopy map.

```
phis = np.linspace(1e-5,10,10) # SV half cone ang, measured up from nadir
thetas = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,361)# SV azimuth, 0 coincides with the vel vector

X,Y = np.meshgrid(thetas,phis)
Z   = np.sin(X)**10 + np.cos(10 + Y*X) * np.cos(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
im = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,shading='auto') 

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)
ax.grid(True)
```

that results in
[image]

Over a cartopy map like this...

```
flatMap = ccrs.PlateCarree()
resolution = '110m'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=flatMap)

ax.imshow(np.tile(np.array([[cfeature.COLORS['water'] * 255]], dtype=np.uint8), [2, 2, 1]), origin='upper', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[-180, 180, -180, 180])
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))
ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,shading='auto') 
gc.collect()
```

[image]

I'd like to project this polar plot over an arbitrary lon/lat... I can convert the polar theta/phi into lon/lat, but lon/lat coords (used on the map) are more 'cartesian like' than polar, hence you cannot just substitute lon/lat for theta/phi ... This is a conceptual problem. How would you tackle it?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the data must be prepared/transformed into certain projection coordinates for use as input. And the instruction/option of the data's CRS must be specified correctly when used in the plot statement.

In your specific case, you need to transform your data into (long,lat) values.

```
XX = X/np.pi*180  # wrap around data in EW direction
YY = Y*9          # spread across N hemisphere
```

And plot it with an instruction `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()`.

```
ax.pcolormesh(XX,YY,Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,shading='auto', 
          transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image: polar_data_plot]

The same (XX,YY,Z) data set can be plotted on orthographic projection.

[image: ortho]

**Edit1**

Update of the code and plots.

Part 1 (Data)

```
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

#
# Part 1
#
phis = np.linspace(1e-5,10,10) # SV half cone ang, measured up from nadir
thetas = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,361)# SV azimuth, 0 coincides with the vel vector

X,Y = np.meshgrid(thetas,phis)
Z   = np.sin(X)**10 + np.cos(10 + Y*X) * np.cos(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
im = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,shading='auto') 

ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)
ax.grid(True)
```

Part 2 The required code and output.

```
#
# Part 2
#
flatMap = ccrs.PlateCarree()
resolution = '110m'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6), dpi=96)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=flatMap)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', 
            resolution, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7, 
            facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())


def scale_position(lat_deg, lon_deg, rad_deg):
    # Two operations:
    # 1. manipulates X,Y data and get (XX,YY)
    # 2. create proper projection of (XX,YY), `rotpole_proj`
    # Returns: XX,YY,rotpole_proj

    # For X data
    XX = X/np.pi*180   #always wrap around EW direction

    # For Y data
    # The cone data: min=0, max=10  -->  (90-rad),90
    # rad_deg = radius of the display area
    top = 90
    btm = top-rad_deg
    YY = btm + (Y/Y.max())*rad_deg

    # The proper coordinate system
    rotpole_proj = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_latitude=lat_deg, pole_longitude=lon_deg)
    # Finally,
    return XX,YY,rotpole_proj

# Location 1 (Asia)
XX1, YY1, rotpole_proj1 = scale_position(20, 100, 20)
ax.pcolormesh(XX1, YY1, Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, 
              transform=rotpole_proj1) 

# Location 2 (Europe)
XX2, YY2, rotpole_proj2 = scale_position(62, -6, 8)
ax.pcolormesh(XX2, YY2, Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,
              transform=rotpole_proj2) 

# Location 3 (N America)
XX3, YY3, rotpole_proj3 = scale_position(29, -75, 30)
ax.pcolormesh(XX3, YY3, Z, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r,shading='auto', 
              transform=rotpole_proj3) 

#gc.collect()
plt.show()
```

[image: storms]

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I was clear. I want to project the polar plot onto the globe from a specific location above that globe, so the entire polar plot will occupy a very small portion of the globe. I'll post a partial solution that may help. Thanks again however!

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks a ton sir... good info and a great example. I thought cartopy should be able to do these xforms, now I have a template for how.

Comment: For everyone else that reads this -- a little more explanation. @swatchai 's scale_position() essentially rotates the globe's coordinate system to the north pole. It takes the X (theta, az) coordinates and transforms them from radians to deg. It then maps the Y (phi, el) to a lat range from 90 N down to 90-rad_deg.  He creates the rotated_pole crs with the desired location for the data plot and returns the mapped XX and YY. These can now be used in the plot pcolormesh with the rotated_pole transform.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does NOT account for the projection point being at some altitude above the globe... I can do that part, so I really have trouble mapping the meshgrid to lon/lat so the work with the PREVIOUSLY GENERATES values of Z.

Here's a simple mapping directly from polar to cart:

```
X_cart = np.array([[p*np.sin(t) for p in phis] for t in thetas]).T
Y_cart = np.array([[p*np.cos(t) for p in phis] for t in thetas]).T
# Need to map cartesian XY to Z that is compatbile with above... 

Z_cart = np.sin(X)**10 + np.cos(10 + Y*X) * np.cos(X) # This Z does NOT map to cartesian X,Y
print(X_cart.shape,Y_cart.shape,Z_cart.shape) 

flatMap = ccrs.PlateCarree()
resolution = '110m'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=flatMap)

ax.imshow(np.tile(np.array([[cfeature.COLORS['water'] * 255]], dtype=np.uint8), [2, 2, 1]), origin='upper', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[-180, 180, -180, 180])
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))

im = ax.pcolormesh(X_cart*2,Y_cart*2, Z_cart, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, shading='auto') # c=mapper.to_rgba(Z_cart), cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r) 


gc.collect()
```

Which maps the polar plot center to lon/lat (0,0):

[image]

I'm close... I somehow need to move my cartesian coords to the proper lon/lat (the satellite sub-point) and then scale it appropriately. Have the set of lon/lat but I'm screwing up the meshgrid somehow... ???

The sphere_intersect() routine returns lon/lat for projection of theta/phi on the globe (that works)... The bit that doesn't work is building the meshgrid that replaces X,Y:

```
lons = np.array([orbits.sphere_intersect(SV_pos_vec, SV_vel_vec, az << u.deg, el << u.deg, 
                                        lonlat=True)[0] for az in thetas for el in phis], dtype='object')
lats = np.array([orbits.sphere_intersect(SV_pos_vec, SV_vel_vec, az << u.deg, el << u.deg, 
                                        lonlat=True)[1] for az in thetas for el in phis], dtype='object')

long, latg = np.meshgrid(lons,lats) # THIS IS A PROBLEM I BELIEVE...
```

and the pcolormesh makes a mess...